# How to map a file in a docker volume

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I have a particular use case in a docker-compose file. The below is an extract of such file that should be sufficient to demonstrate the issue.

```
version: '2'

volumes: 
  data: 
    #external: true
    driver: rancher-nfs

services:
  harbor-setupwrapper:
    image: mreferre/harbor-setupwrapper:1.1.1-1
    container_name: harbor-setupwrapper
    volumes:
      - data:/data
    command: ["/harbor/harbor-setupwrapper.sh"]
    network_mode: "none"

  ui:
    image: vmware/harbor-ui:v1.1.1
    container_name: harbor-ui
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - data:/harbor_storage 
      - /data/secretkey:/etc/ui/key:z
    depends_on:
      - harbor-setupwrapper
    entrypoint:
      - /bin/sh
      - -c
    command:
      - /configui/entrypointui.sh
```

Basically my use case is as follow: I create a docker volume (`data`) that I mount in a setup container (I am using a regular NFS driver). That setup container generates a bunch of configuration files inside the volume.

I then need to map that entire volume inside another container:

`- data:/harbor_storage`

This works just fine and in the `ui` container I can see the content of the `data` volume inside the container `/harbor_storage` directory.

However I would also need to map a specific file in the `data` volume inside a specific directory inside the `ui` container:

`-/data/secretkey:/etc/ui/key:z`

This doesn't work as it basically maps a `/data/secretkey` directory local to the host into a `/etc/ui/key:z` directory inside the container.

In reality `secretkey` is a file in the `data` volume (which is what I want to map to the file `/etc/ui/key:z`.

I have also tried with the tweak in the syntax to see if I can tell compose that I am referring to the `data` volume but compose complains about the syntax being wrong. This is what I tried (with no luck):

`- data/secretkey:/etc/ui/key:z`

Any thought appreciated.

P.S. I know I could call a small script that copies `/harbor_storage/secretkey` into `/etc/ui/key` but I am still hoping to not have to go down that rathole and be able to map it like I am trying to do.

Comment: You can mount that rathole script without needing to create a new image. Put the script where docker-compose see it, mount into the container, then run it as your `command`, chained to the real command

Comment: Thanks. Given I already have a script that does "things" before starting the actual process in the container, I opted to tweak the existing script to place the files properly. It worked fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is currently not possible to mount subdirectories of volumes.  You have to either extract that key from that volume and mount it, or copy or symlink it.

Answer (score 1):

just to let the new people know. 
Now it's possible (since the version 2.1.0.X of docker, engine 19.x.x) and the way is the same as the folder mappings:

```
volumes:
  - ~/dev/environment/configuration.properties:/opt/data/configuration.properties
```

Comment: Can You please elaborate on Your answer? It is not clear how that mapping would work in the context of the question.

Comment: Can you do this with a dockerfile instead of docker compose?